# java - Implementing Adjacency lists using Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, nested

This is what i have :

```
class Node {

    Integer value;
    ArrayList<Integer> adjList;

    public Node(Integer val, ArrayList<Integer> l) {
        value = val;
        Collections.sort(l);
        adjList = l;
    }
}
```

This is what i want :

```
class Node {

    Integer value;
    ArrayList<Node> adjList;

    public Node(Integer val, ArrayList<Integer> l) {
        value = val;
        Collections.sort(l,/*some comparator*/);
        adjList = l;
    }
}
```

so that i can do this :

```
private void process(){
    Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    while(vertices.size() > 2){
        Node v1 = vertices.get(r.nextInt(vertices.size()));
        Node v2 = v1.adjList.get(r.nextInt(v1.adjList.size()));
        contract(v1,v2); // Randomized contraction algorithm aka Karger's Min Cut algorithm
    }
}
```

But here's whats bugging me :

If i declare adjacency lists to be of type `ArrayList<Node>`, then will each element of this list store a pointer or keep an entire copy of a node (and thus nest one arraylist inside another... to infinity! ) ?

I want it to be stored as pointers. what to do here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike C(++), Java *always* uses pointers for objects. This means that the list will only store those references.

The lists in your nodes, then, will also store a reference to other lists, but each list exists only once in memory.